# How to make a anything else function on Python

Tags: python, loops, authentication

I'm new to Python and learning at my own speed in my spare time, however, so far, this is the part of my program I am having trouble with:

```
name = input('\nEnter username: ');
if name == 'Bradley':
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if pwd == '1234':
                print("\nWelcome," , name, "")
                time.sleep(2)

command = input("\nEnter Command: ");
```

The code itself works fine, however, is it possible to  have something along the lines of, if it isn't `'Bradley'` or `'1234'`, then print `'Invalid username or password'`, and then make it loop back to that part of the code. Essentially it's a local logon script.

I'd like it so the 'user' doesn't know if they've got a wrong username or password until both have been entered, kind of like a real life scenario.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a loop, which you break out of as soon as you get the right answers, but otherwise just loop through again.

```
while True:
    name = input('\nEnter username: ');
    if name == 'Bradley':
        pwd = input('Enter password: ')
        if pwd == '1234':
            print("\nWelcome," , name, "")
            time.sleep(2)
            break
    print("Invalid username or password")
```

Now, if the name was 'Bradley' and the password was '1234', you will `break` out of that loop. Otherwise, you won't, you'll just do it all again. And since `True` is always true, you'll keep doing it forever, until you get the answers you want.

---

You can do this with any kind of loop, not just a `while True`. For example, if you want to give them three chances, and then bail out:

```
for i in range(3):
    name = input('\nEnter username: ');
    # etc.
else:
    print('Too many tries, go learn how to hack better')
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

> I'd like it so the 'user' doesn't know if they've got a wrong username or password until both have been entered, kind of like a real life scenario.

Then just move the `pwd = …` part outside the `if name == 'Bradley'` part:

```
    name = input('\nEnter username: ');
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if name == 'Bradley':
        if pwd == '1234':
            # etc.
```

And now that you've done that, you can simplify things:

```
    name = input('\nEnter username: ');
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if name == 'Bradley' and pwd == '1234':
        # etc.
```

And now that you just have a single `if`, you can attach an `else` to it, for code that runs unless both `name` and `pwd` match. (Go back and look at the nested `if` statements and you should be able to figure out why it would be hard to add an `else` that way.)

```
    name = input('\nEnter username: ');
    pwd = input('Enter password: ')
    if name == 'Bradley' and pwd == '1234':
        # etc.
    else:
        print("Invalid username or password")
```